# IOS Push notification triggered by variable crossing user-defined limit

Tags: php, ios, push-notification

I am trying to get my head around push notifications for IOS.

I currently fetch values from a JSON format and use them as a double to display the current price of an item.

I would like the user to be able to set a push notification that gets triggered when that price crosses a user-defined upper or lower limit but I can't seem to find any information on how to do this?

I'm guessing this has to be done in php on the apns server?

I've scanned tutorials but I'm only good at Obj-C right now so apart from following tutorial code I'm just fiddling with the php.Tutorials also don't seem to cover much of sending and using variables in the mix.

The functionality very much resembles the push notification for Bitcoin prices in the ZeroBlock IOS app.

Or would it be better to have the app check prices every 30 seconds in the background and then throw up a local notification to the user?

Can anyone push me in the right direction?

Comment: http://urbanairship.com/, there's also a ton of GIT repositories ... use Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want this to be done server-side. So the user within the app would configure what price they want the trigger to happen at, and you would send this information to your server. Then your server would send them a push notification when this condition is met. You would not want the app doing frequent requests to the server, or be kept running constantly in the background.

There are services such as Parse and Urban Airship that can handle the push notifications side of things for you. You'll have to set up other stuff in order to be able to determine when to send them and such, but these services will help you.

I would recommend finding tutorials on PHP, since that would be useful to know. But also you should find tutorials on integrating and using Parse and Urban Airship (I would probably recommend Parse over Urban Airship, but it's your choice).

Comment: Thanks Parse.com seems like the most helpful so far! Push is working fine, I can fetch and compare to an url in cloud code automatically, just need help now on how to iterate through the keys on a per DeviceToken basis which is hard to find it seems...